# Show android Keyboard with code, without using a GUI-element

Tags: android, keyboard

How can I show the Android keyboard with code. I dont want to use it with an GUI-element, just show it.

Comment: I want to show it, to make the user possible to send key-events to my app.

Comment: The app is running in a GlSurfaceView. When I long press the Menu-Button, the keyboard shows. I want to show it by code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`showSoftInput()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html#showSoftInput%28int,%20android.os.ResultReceiver%29) on `InputMethodManager`.